# Questions about GWT base Url

Tags: java, gwt, deployment

Say I'm hosting a project at http://example.com/foo. I put all of the GWT files (which are generated in the /war/ directory after compiling) in http://example.com/foo/GwtModule directory.

Then on my host page, which is http://example.com/foo/bar, I put the following in the HTML:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/foo/GwtModule/GwtModule.noCache.js"></script>`.

My questions are:

- Will GWT know to fetch its resources (e.g css files) from foo/GwtModule folder rather than trying to get them from foo/bar folder?
- If I wanted to send a HTTP request to foo/signup, would `GWT.getModuleBaseUrl() + "signup"` work or will I have to parse the base url, remove "/bar" from it and replace it with "/signup"?
- If I run the code locally as well as on a web server, will GWT automatically determine if the base url is `http://localhost/foo/bar` or http://example.com/foo/bar , or do I need to hard-code the base urls somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will GWT know to fetch its resources (e.g css files) from foo/GwtModule folder rather than trying to get them from foo/bar folder?

Yes.
GWT always resolves the *module base* from the script URL (or a special `<meta name='gwt:property'>`)

> If I wanted to send a HTTP request to foo/signup, would GWT.getModuleBaseUrl() + "signup" work or will I have to parse the base url, remove "/bar" from it and replace it with "/signup"?

`GWT.getModuleBaseURL()` will be `/foo/GwtModule/`.
You can either use `GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "/../signup"` or `"GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "/signup"`, in your case they'll both resolve to the same `/foo/signup` URL.

> If I run the code locally as well as on a web server, will GWT automatically determine if the base url is `http://localhost/foo/bar` or `http://example.com/foo/bar`, or do I need to hard-code the base urls somewhere?

See answer to first question.
That means you'll have to use `<script src="GwtModule/GwtModule.nocache.js">` or `<script src="/foo/GwtModule/GwtModule.nocache.js">` in your host page.